# Installation / configuration of GeoServer on Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: geoserver, installation

I can probably sort this out (eventually) but perhaps someone has some magic?
After installing GeoServer, when I attempt to start the service:

```
dfcactual@intrain-home:/usr/share/geoserver/bin $ bash startup.sh

GEOSERVER DATA DIR is /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir

ERROR : Nothing to start, exiting ...


Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

Context:
I am moving a (working) prototype application from a Windows machine to a small farm of Pis. This is slightly out of the mainstream; I am hoping that with a Pi 5 and external SSD the performance will be acceptable.

The sequence of installations has been:

- Install PostgreSQL
- Install PostGIS
- Load selected OpenStreetMap data
- Confirm Java is present (it's a default installation for Pi-os)

```
openjdk version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb12u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+7-Debian-1deb12u1, mixed mode)
```

- Because of this issue, I manually installed jetty  (sudo apt install jetty9)

```
Package: jetty9
Version: 9.4.50-4+deb12u2
Priority: optional
Section: java
Maintainer: Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 761 kB
Depends: adduser, apache2-utils, default-jre-headless (>= 2:1.8) | java8-runtime-headless, libeclipse-jdt-core-java, libjetty9-extra-java (>= 9.4.50-4+deb12u2), libjetty9-java (>= 9.4.50-4+deb12u2), lsb-base
Recommends: authbind
Homepage: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/
Download-Size: 272 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
Description: Java servlet engine and webserver
 Jetty is an Open Source HTTP Servlet Server written in 100% Java.
 It is designed to be light weight, high performance, embeddable,
 extensible and flexible, thus making it an ideal platform for serving
 dynamic HTTP requests from any Java application.
```

This manual installation made no difference.

I have run various options of the "java -jar ..../start.jar" with nothing obvious (to me) reported.
I have modified the startup.sh script to spit out some information about the command line it creates:
[image]

Based on the documentation for Java 17 that says the Marlin rendered needs to be disabled, I have done that in the startup script. (This made no difference in the output).

I will continue to flog this, but has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Life is good, and GeoServer is running. Based on Ian's suggestion that "this is fixed in recent versions", I downloaded and unpacked geoserver-2.24.x-latest-bin.zip. The server and the admin page now come up. Thanks, Ian. [The version with issues is geoserver-2.24.2-bin.zip, for anyone keeping score].

Answer (score 0):

try from the directory above - so in `/usr/share/geoserver` run `bash ./bin/start.sh` - I believe that this is fixed in recent releases.

Comment: Thank you. May I assume you mean bash, not java in the suggested command line? I didn't get different results starting from the geoserver home.. In my (copy of) the startup.sh script I added the --debug flag and get a lot more information, but it still doesn't tell me what's missing. I intend to try to modify the Main class in the source code so that it spits out the name of the offending module ... however I have a lot to learn before I get that done.